# touchesBegan issues since adding a scrollview

Tags: uiscrollview, keyboard, uitextfield, touchesbegan

I have been using this code to hide my keyboard.

```
 // Keyboard hide
-(IBAction)ReturnKeyButton:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    [[self view] endEditing:TRUE];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [[self view] endEditing:TRUE];
}
```

This has worked perfectly and I don't feel there is any issue with this code normally. Now when I click off the text fields nothing happens. My issue has popped up after deciding to move all my content to a scrollview. Is there any known issues with doing this i.e the main UIView needs to be linked to my scrollview? I have a theory that the "[self view]" section needs to changed to suit the new scrollview. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Im new to scripting and although I may not know what each element of my scripting is, I do understand what this script does. It has been working for me as a means to close my keyboard either when an allocated button is pressed or simply when the user touches off the text field. The ReturnKeyButton function still works so naturally I assume it is the touchesBegan feature that is causing the issue. I have gone though the view settings to ensure User interaction is enabled but I still feel as if there is an easy fix that Im not seeing.
If you don't know you don't have to comment

Comment: Don't worry. I found the solution within the script of this [youtube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqnJ-glyQsA) this method works well, it just requires a lot of lines of simple code. Suits my purpose perfectly.